# Swimmer survival plot in R

Tags: r

Here is my dataset obtained from datapasta:

```
data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE,patient_ID = c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19"),Time = c(1596,1514,356,2085,1921,318,83,328,815,1854,159,240,821,720,2315,1800,99,205,177)
```

I'm trying to obtain a Swimmer's plot for this data. I have entered the following:

```
H_N_outcomes_first20$Time <- as.numeric(H_N_outcomes_first20$Time)
H_N_outcomes_first20$patient_ID <- as.character(H_N_outcomes_first20$patient_ID)
library(swimplot)
swimmer_plot(df=H_N_outcomes_first20, id="patient_ID", end= "Time", fill='lightblue', width=0.85)
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = df[, end] ~ df[, id]) :invalid type (list) for variable 'df[, end]'
```

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/swimplot/swimplot.pdf

Comment: Where does `swimmer_plot()` come from?

Comment: The error message says that the `df` parameter should not be given the entire dataframe. Read the help page for `swimmer_plot` and make sure the class of your arguments accord with what is described in the Arguments section.